# Clone Class with class variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rubygems, rails-i18n

I have some third [party class](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/71a51b3243da7ca65885d2f81d91be15c92402a2/lib/i18n/config.rb), which extensive uses class variables:

```
class Config
  def default_locale
    @@default_locale ||= :en
  end
end
```

This class (I18n::Config) is quit large, and there are a lot of class variables. It is not a case to completely rewrite it.

I need to get an instance of this class, which **will not affect anyway** original Config class variables.

This is needed for Rails app, where I try to make I18n configurable **per each request** and **thread safe** at the same time.

For thread safety I will use [RequestStore](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store). I need to put there an independent Config instance, which will not affect original class variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call .dup on the class to get an identical, but independent anonymous class that can be initiated.

```
config1 = I18n.config
config2 = I18n::Config.new # same class
config3 = I18n::Config.dup.new # different class
config1.default_locale # :en
config2.default_locale # :en
config3.default_locale # :en

config2.default_locale = :de

config1.default_locale # :de
config2.default_locale # :de
config3.default_locale # :en (unchanged)
```